# Compare file dates from two directories

Tags: date, file-comparison

I have two directories with files with the same name.
Basically I want to replace dir1/file.txt with dir2/file.txt if the creation date of dir1/file.txt is more recent. But i think I'm missing something in the if condition.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /dir1/*; do
        nameFIRR=$(basename "$i")
        dateINPUT="$(date -r $i)"
        dateOUTPUT="$(date -r /dir2/$nameFIRR)"

        if [ $dateINPUT -ge $dateOUTPUT ];
        then
         cp -u $i /dir2/$nameFIRR
        fi
done
```

Comment: Try using Bash's built-in -nt file test. From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html, you should be able to drop the date shell calls, and replace your if with `if [ $nameFIRR -nt /dir2/$nameFIRR ]`

Comment: My point was that with `cp`'s `-u` option you don't need all this! `cp -u dir1/* dir2`...

Comment: Note `date -r` and also `test -nt` and `cp -u` use the _last modification_ time of the file(s), which may or may not be the same as _creation_ time. Unix utilities rarely support creation time because original Unix filesystems didn't store it, and even today only some do.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common solutions:

1. `rsync` is one:

`rsync` is a powerful tool with many, many options; see `man rsync` for details. But for a simple synopsis, the command is:

> rsync [options] source  destination

In your case, this should do it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
rsync -t dir1/file.txt dir2/file.txt
```

2. the 'copy' (`cp`) command with the `-u` option is another (per Stephen Kitt's comment):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cp -u dir1/file.txt dir2/file.txt
```